# Setting multiple alter statements on a single column in one command SQL

Tags: postgresql, ddl

I am trying to modify a column data type and name in one command.

Is it possible to apply multiple alter statements on one column in one code line? Is that the correct syntax?

```
ALTER TABLE tb_table
ALTER COLUMN colum_date 
SET DATA TYPE TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
RENAME COLUMN colum_date TO colum_timestamp;
```

I have been looking for related bibliography but could not find much information on the web.

Answer (score 6):

According to the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-altertable.html) renaming a column is an action that cannot be combined with others but requires its own statement. So no, you cannot do what you want in one statement.

But you can do it in one transaction. Setting the datatype and setting the `NOT NULL` constraint requires two actions though. But both of that actions can be in one statement.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
ALTER TABLE tb_table
            ALTER COLUMN colum_date 
                         SET DATA TYPE TIMESTAMP,
            ALTER COLUMN colum_date
                         SET NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE tb_table
            RENAME COLUMN colum_date
                          TO colum_timestamp;
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: Wow... I thought DDLs were not transactional. Maybe I got that from Oracle, idk.

Comment: @TheImpaler: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Transactional_DDL_in_PostgreSQL:_A_Competitive_Analysis sheds some light on this.

Comment: You learn something new every day. Thank you for the link.

Comment: @stickybit would all that be possible to implement in a plpgsql function?

Comment: @KlauRau: Not in a function but in a procedure it should work.

Comment: This also answers my question on how to add multiple constraints on a sing column.

Comment: Apropos you comment to @stickybit isn’t a plpgsql procedure actually a void function?