# Rename and add column in same query in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, alter-table

Let's say I have a table `Student` with just 2 columns - `id bigint`, `name varchar(50)`.

I'm trying to rename it and add column in a same single query in PostgreSQL version 11.16 like below:

```
ALTER TABLE student
  RENAME COLUMN name TO fullname, 
  ADD COLUMN roll_no varchar(30);
```

But I got this error:

> Syntax error at or near "ADD"

Is it possible? If not, why?

Comment: No, not possible. You could execute two ALTER statements in a single transaction. And why it's not supported? Because nobody has build it yet.

Comment: im not sure but maybe that will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70176036/setting-multiple-alter-statements-on-a-single-column-in-one-command-sqlhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/70176036/setting-multiple-alter-statements-on-a-single-column-in-one-command-sql

Comment: @frank-heikens, But I can add two columns in a single alter query.

Comment: @Md.NowshadHasan: Yes, that's correct, you can add multiple columns in a single statement. But not rename and add in a single statement. Just check the manual

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that is not possible. I got this from the [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23274679/renaming-multiple-columns-in-one-statement-with-postgresql) answer. One **RENAME** is possible for only one statement. Even multiple **RENAME commands** are also not possible. Here is the [postgres manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html).